# Lost account on Borderlands 2

Tags: borderlands-2

On my PS3, I was a level 18 as Assassin but when I went onto my brother's account and logged into my own account, it said I was level 1 and as Axton. When I went back onto my own account it said level 1, but when I went into my saved data it still has my profile level 18. Anyone know what's the problem and how I get my account back?

Comment: Did you try "Select Character" from the main menu?

Answer (score 2):

Well... There are a number of things you can do, each of which is not too terribly difficult.

First make sure you have selected the correct memory device when you "Choose save location" It can't save or access your character from a device that has no memory of it.

Second, if you press (Y) for Xbox or (triangle) for PS3, while at the main menu, it will bring up a list of characters on that memory device as well as the option to create a new character.

If both of these fail, go to your memory storage and make sure you are on the right account for the particular save (while in memory, it will say under the size of the file on the right hand side which account it belongs to for the Xbox, at least).

Should all of these fail, you can always start a new character and scourge the baddies of Pandora anew.